# I am not able to click with SeleniumBase

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, gmail, seleniumbase

I am using Python to automate my Gmail to change the password of my Spotfy account

```
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://www.google.com/gmail/about/")
    sb.click('a[data-action="sign in"]')
    sb.type('input[type="email"]', "*******@gmail.com")
    sb.click('button:contains("Next")')
    sb.sleep(5)
    sb.type('input[type="password"]', "********")
    sb.click('button:contains("Next")')
    sb.sleep(10)
    sb.click('span:contains("Reset Password")')
    input("Press Enter to close the browser...")
    sb.quit()
```

The problem is at:
sb.click('span:contains("Reset Password")')

Whatever I try to click on the email that contains "Reset Password," it never works.I have tried several ways: Xpath, CSS selector, ID, name, and more

To check if I was doing it right, I tested clicking on other buttons on the page as "inbox," "starred," "sent," and "compose," and all worked fine

I would appreciate any help

Thank you in advance